# python list of lists indexing

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to do something with the python list of list but I found something weird about the indexing.
If I want to create a 2*2 "matrix", I do

```
matrix = [[0]*2]*2
```

Then if I want to change the first row first column by using, say,

```
matrix[0][0] = 1
```

I will get `[[1,0],[1,0]]`, instead of `[[1,0],[0,0]]`. Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: @DSM -- quite quick... And it wasn't even your answer.  Nicely done sir!

Comment: Incredibly quick I would say :)

Answer (score 6):

Using the `*` operator on a list creates a shallow copy, so `[[0]*2]*2` is equivalent to the following:

```
inner = [0, 0]
matrix = [inner, inner]
```

Because both locations in `matrix` are a reference to the same list, any modification to one will modify the other.  Instead, use the following:

```
matrix = [[0]*2 for i in range(2)]
```